# Show overlay on image when hovering over a link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show an overlay on an image when there is a hover over the link.

I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="blog-entry-link">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
   </div>
   <header class="blog-entry-header clr">
      <h2 class="blog-entry-title entry-title">
         <a>Title</a>
      </h2>
   </header>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
header.blog-entry-header.clr h2.blog-entry-title.entry-title a:hover + .thumbnail .overlay {
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I've tried using Next-sibling combinator (+), Subsequent-sibling combinator (~) and Child combinator (>) but no luck!

By the way, I'm using a::before to stretch the link over .blog-entry-link. So I need maintain the styling on link hover.

```
.entry-title a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I also tried something like this but no cigar.

```
.blog-entry-link:has(> a:hover ) {

    .blog-entry-link .thumbnail .overlay {
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to apply a hover effect on a link (`<a>`) and then target a sibling element (`<span class="overlay">`) to show an overlay on an image.

Your current CSS selector is:

```css
header.blog-entry-header.clr h2.blog-entry-title.entry-title a:hover + .thumbnail .overlay {
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This selector is trying to target an element with class "overlay" that is a descendant of an element with class "thumbnail" that is an adjacent sibling of an `<a>` element that is a descendant of an `<h2>` element with specific classes.

The issue might be that `.thumbnail` is not an immediate sibling of the `<a>` element. It's wrapped in a different div.

You can adjust your HTML and CSS as follows:

```html
<div class="blog-entry-link">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
   </div>
   <header class="blog-entry-header clr">
      <h2 class="blog-entry-title entry-title">
         <a>Title</a>
      </h2>
   </header>
</div>
```

```css
.blog-entry-link:hover .thumbnail .overlay {
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

In this CSS, we're using the `.blog-entry-link:hover` selector to target the `.overlay` element when you hover over the entire `.blog-entry-link` div. This way, you don't need to worry about sibling relationships, as the overlay is nested within the same parent container.

Make sure you adjust the CSS properties (`-moz-opacity`, `-webkit-opacity`, `opacity`) to apply the desired overlay effect.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm using a::before to stretch the link over .blog-entry-link. So I need maintain the styling on link hover.